# Eclipse dot does not auto suggest

Tags: eclipse

I am using Eclipse 3.7.1 classic.

When I type a class, it does not show the auto suggest. I dont know why, before it can pop up the function.

I have not changed any configuration of the eclipse.

For example, when I type `System`, it does not pop up the auto suggest, like `out.println`.

Comment: I know why, if somebody meets the same problem, please refer this solution.
Go to
Windows/Preferences/Java/Editor/Content Assist/Advanced and pressed "Restore Defaults". All works now. For some reason the "Java Proposals" was unchecked.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Preferences->Java->Editor->Content Assist. 
Make sure you have "Enable Auto activation" Checked

If it doesn't work, go to Advanced section: Java->Editor->Content Assist->Advanced 
In the "Select the proposal kinds contained in the 'default' content assist list",
have "Java Proposals" Checked 
OR 
Restore Defaults, Apply and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Start `eclipse` with the `-clean` parameter to delete old stored values.

If you installed new plugins you should disabled them in the `prefrences-> workspace` and see if one is blocking the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you have a syntax error that you have not noticed higher up in the class, such as forgetting to close a method with a } or missing a terminating ";".

Try the same in a new project. If you still have the problem I'd try the suggestion by "Udo Fholl".